# Recommended framework for web app development

Tags: web-apps, web-development, framework, node.js, angular

I need to create a web app for a personal project, i know basic programming and i want to code it from zero (learning new stuff on the way), but i don't really know what combination would fit best for my needs.

**This app needs to have**:

-A login form, and a database of users with different privileges (i want one type user to be able to upload and modify content (admin), one that can only view the content (consumer) and one above all admin users (super admin).

-Every modification made to the content needs to be logged, and it has to say who did it and when. (so i can avoid troublemakers ;))

-The visuals need to be pretty but efficient, i have to be able to make some charts (animated pie charts, bar charts)

-Also need to upload pictures to make a gallery (for every user a different gallery, and info about when and where the picture was taken)

-Needs to be responsive for view on all devices, and maybe in the future with an android app.

Those are the more important things this app needs. Please if someone can guide me on this, i would appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

I think [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) is a good framework for realize this project.

It's a special [Python](https://www.python.org/) Web Framework. You can directly create and administrate you're Database with code (look around models).

There is some special functions for create forms, views, GUI...
Moreover, you can use all library from Python like [MatPlotLib](https://matplotlib.org/) for your charts or [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) for you responsive design.

I hope this information will help you !

Comment: Hey Malecto, i'm checking it out right now, thanks for your answer, i think is very helpful

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP, I recommend [Codeigniter](https://codeigniter.com), but MVC frameworks usually don't come with user authentication systems, audit logs, responsive design, graphs and image and file uploads. MVC frameworks typically expect you to build that yourself.

For charts you can use [Amcharts](https://www.amcharts.com/) or [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/).